# Use trait in Laravel database migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration, traits

My superior told me I could create a `seeder`-like `trait` which I can then use inside a `migration`. When the migration is being run on the server the database automatically gets seeded while migrating instead of running a separate seeder after the migration succeeded.

Now I created a trait which I included in the database migration.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Module\Module;
use App\Models\Plan\Plan;

/**
 * PlanAndModuleGenerator class.
 */
trait PlanAndModuleGenerator
{
    private static $plans = [
        'free',
        'basic',
        'premium',
    ];

    public function up()
    {

        foreach ($this->plans as $planName) {

            // Get or create Plan.
            $plan = Plan::create([
                'machine_name' => '',
                'name' => $planName
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

My superior told me they did this before, but I can't find anything like this on the internet. I included my trait like this.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use App\Services\PlanAndModuleGenerator;

class ModulePlan extends Migration
{
    use PlanAndModuleGenerator;
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('module_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('plan_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('module_id');

            $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('plans');
            $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('module_plan');
    }
}
```

When I run the migration the `up` function inside my `trait` isn't executed. I know this because the `Plan` table isn't seeded yet. Any ideas on how I might tackle this? As my superior isn't in the office the upcoming days and I can't access the repository where they did this before.

Besides this, can anyone tell me how I can properly debug this trait? The way I am doing this now, just running the migration and wait for errors, seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: it isn't run because you are overriding the `up` method by defining it on the class that uses the trait ... look into how traits work: [PHP Manual - OOP - Traits - Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason for this trait at all, but if you really want to use it you would need to alias the `up` method of the trait and then call that in your `up` method of the migration:

```
class ModulePlan extends Migration
{
    use PlanAndModuleGenerator { up as traitUp; }

    public function up()
    {
        ...
        $this->traitUp();
    }
}
```

It would be better to just use a different name for the method in the Trait, but there is no reason for this trait in the first place it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitly not work because you have two `up` methods, one in your `trait` and the one in your `migration`. You need to delete the `up` in your migration and use the one in your trait as shown below. Here is the trait

```html
<?php

namespace App\Services;


use App\Models\Plan\Plan;
use App\Models\Module\Module;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

/**
 * PlanAndModuleGenerator class.
 */
trait PlanAndModuleGenerator
{
    private static $plans = [
        'free',
        'basic',
        'premium',
    ];

    public function up()
    {
        $createmigration = Schema::create('module_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('plan_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('module_id');

            $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('plans');
            $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules');
        });

        if ($createmigration) {
            foreach ($this->plans as $planName) {
                // Get or create Plan.
                $plan = Plan::create([
                    'machine_name' => '',
                    'name' => $planName
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Confirm first that the migration was created before creating your Plan.

Here is how your migration should look like

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use App\Services\PlanAndModuleGenerator;

class ModulePlan extends Migration
{
    use PlanAndModuleGenerator;
    
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('module_plan');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: at that point why use the trait at all, why not have it all in the migration? now you cant see your schema without diving into a trait

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder@create` returns void

Comment: Thank you, I did not know it returns `void`, nevertheless @Baspa's problem was using the `up` method twice.